# Any example to using vesting pallet?

Tags: pallet, vesting-balance

I have integrated the vesting pallet to my chain.
Do we have any example how to use it and and how to prepare vesting config?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps, please mark this as acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example of full implementation vesting pallet with config. Kilt github: https://github.com/KILTprotocol/kilt-node

Answer (score 4):

You can take reference from Substrate Vesting Pallet runtime configuration https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1388